# How to close the command prompt when running a batch exe on windows server 2008 via task scheduler?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I was wondering if its possible to stop displaying command appearing when running the console batch app(exe) using windows task scheduler. Is it possible to not display it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a VBScript to run the batch file hidden

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("yourbatchfile.bat"), 0, True
```

Save that as `.vbs` and run that from the scheduled task instead of the batch file.

Comment: i have C# console app and i am using exe file to run the app

Comment: @updev Then just get the C# app to run the vbscript instead. Unless you don't have access to the code?